# Change Controller name to productname

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create more SEO friendly URL for my products which are stored in the database.

How can I get ProductName from the URL?

For example:

```
http://domain.com/ProductName
```

Where ProductName is not Controller. I need to validate the ProductName from the controller and display it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be friendlier to have the url like `http://domain.com/product/{Productname}`?

Comment: By default CI routes, I have this Url for products. but the client want some main products with the url like in my question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can make use of CI routes to achieve this

Edit Application/config/routes.php

```
$route['/(:any)'] = "/products/index/$1";
```

Comment: You just butchered the few advantages that codeigniter offers.

Comment: @javed  Using Routes would be better option.

Comment: 1st it broke the whole mvc concept. If you are not using mvc pattern, why you need a mvc framework? 2nd, there is already a wrapper for database. 3rd, even while coming out of the wrapper, the use of deprecated mysql_* functions. 4th, reinventing the wheel again and again, there is already method to get uri segments. 5th, fixing something in so complicated way which can be done with just 1 line through routing. Use the appropriate tools for appropriate actions. I can go on and on but i will advice that the above example shouldn't be followed as it breaks the design patterns.

Comment: What is this I cant even comprehend

Comment: @itachi , I agree with you , I already mention in my answer and comment that, using router would be better option. The above code i wrote for just playing with the hooks when i was new to the CI. it's better to know about the internal working of framework.

Comment: @navneet that comment was in regards to javed's question about what was wrong with it. I know you already clarified in the answer but just giving the reasons to javed.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would create a controller called products that accepts a parameter to find a product from the database:

```
class Products extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($productname)
    {
        $data['product'] = $this->db->get_where('products', array('urlname' => $product))->row_array();
        // other functionality here and view loading
    }
}
```

Then add routing for this scenario (config/routes.php):

```
$route['other/routes/first'] = "their/correct/controller/$1";
$route['/(:any)'] = "/products/index/$1";
```

It's been a while since I used CI but this should help point you in the right direction I hope.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a routing rule in routes.php
Redirect the request to Product controller

```
$route['(:any)'] = "product/$1";
```

In your Product controller, get the product name from URI segment

```
$product_name = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

Comment: Does this reroute all requests to Products controller?

Comment: If the request URL does not match any routing rules before that rule, it will route to Products controller.

Comment: Be sure and clean/filter $product_name before submitting to database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URI Routing (Routing Rules)](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

Routing rules are defined in your application/config/routes.php file. In it you'll see an array called $route that permits you to specify your own routing criteria. Routes can either be specified using wildcards or Regular Expressions

```
$route['/(:any)'] = "/products/index/$1";
```

this example would result in: http://www.example.com/MyProductName/ loading the products class giving the name as parameter.